# Rails 3 - How to redirect with all options and parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Say I have a bunch of routes created for Foo controller:

```
/foos
/foos/1
/foos/1/posts
```

etc.

Now I create a Bar, which is a *subtype* of Foo.  I don't want to confuse users by having the Bars be accessible by the Foo urls, so I created duplicate paths for the Bars.

```
/bars (goes to Foo controller)
/bars/1 (goes to Foo controller)
/bars/1/posts (goes to Posts controller)
```

This all works fine.  The issue is that I have used name routes every where in my application, like

```
def update
  # bla bla bla
  redirect_to foo_path(@foo)
end
```

This will take a user editing a Bar from `/bar/1/edit` to `/foo/1`.  How can I successfully redirect or send them to the correct urls?

I tried to do this in my ApplicationController, which works for GET requests but nothing else:

```
def ensure_correct_path
  if current_foo_is_type_bar && request.path =~ /^\/foo/
    redirect_to request.path.sub(/^\/foo/, /^\/bar/)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, params like what a user has posted (and what HTTP method it is) don't get passed along to the new url. Is there any way to fix this issue quickly and easily (I don't mind something a little hackish)?

Comment: And the config/routes.rb code is? And have you tried using shallow nesting http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html - instead of duplicating routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Foo and Bar are models as well, or you somehow have "Foo" and "Bar" accessible as strings in these actions, you can use `polymorphic_path`:

```
polymorphic_path(@thing.class.downcase)
polymorphic_path("Foo".downcase)
polymorphic_path([:show, @thing.class.downcase, @thing.id])
```

etc...